# Best front-end integration of Angular with back end .NET Core API

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, architecture

I'm trying to figure out the best way to integrate a front-end angular application with .net core back end API.

I've already seen two different methods and wondering why use one over the other?

1. Use the ASP.NET Core with Angular project template (within visual studio) + ASP.NET Core Web API project template.
2. Use a basic stand alone Angular application + ASP.NET Core Web API project template.

Any thoughts or information is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular project template offers the convenience of managing the two apps (API backend and Angular frontend) as a single unit in one solution, and the project can be built and deployed as a single unit.

If you'd like to create and build the backend and Angular frontend apps separately, and host them on different server or sites, or you just want to create an Angular frontend to consume an existing API(s) backend, you can use Angular CLI to create a customized client app without using the Angular project template.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually very good question, i used to create a stand alone both of front-end and backend parts and work with them separatly. It's makes me able to think only about that part or about only that feature i'm working on whatever it is.